# service apache2 restart vs apachectl stop / start

Tags: apache2

I have faced some weird problems in the last days.
When I update my apache2.conf and want to restart my apache2 using `service apache2 restart` there's - as always - no output. Trying to resolve to my website brings up a Cloudflare 521 error (Webserver is down).
When I then try `apachectl stop` (which says no running pid found) and then `apachectl start` it works again.
*`service apache2 stop` and after that `service apache2 start` doesnt work*

/var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Sun Apr 30 22:53:43.646337 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9619] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 30 22:53:43.646450 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9619] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Apr 30 23:01:02.678916 2017] [core:error] [pid 9624] [client 162.158.XX.XX:34442] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://ts.naspyy.eu/
[Sun Apr 30 23:38:29.531546 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9619] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: you might wanna try '/etc/init.d/apache2 restart' also add LogLevel debug to the config.

Comment: [Here](https://hastebin.com/galoqeheca.lua) @NadavTasher

Comment: restart server /+ update apache

Comment: Did that already, @NadavTasher

Comment: killall apache2

Comment: or reinstall apache2